# Long Running Task in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am currently working on WebApi using .Net Core, one of my Api Method will call number of another Api (3rd party), and it will take some time to return response, but I don't want our Api consumers to wait for response, instead I want to return early response i.e The Operation is started. And I ll provide an endpoint to our Consumers through which they can get the status of that operation. For example our consumer calls the api to generate 100k records for which my Api will call around 20 parallel calls to 3rd party api. So I don't want consumer for these 20 apis response.
Currently I have this code:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> GenerateVouchers([FromBody][Required]CreateVoucherRequestModel request, string clientId)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(Request.Method, Request.Path);
        // await _voucherService.ValidateIdempotedKeyWithStatus(clientId, _idempotentHeader);
        //TODO: Check Voucher type & Status before Generating Voucher
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var vouchers = new List<VoucherCreateResponseModel>();
        var batchSize = 5000;
        int numberOfBatches = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)request.quantity / batchSize);
        int totalVoucherQuantity = request.quantity;
        request.quantity = 5000;
        var tasks = new List<Task<VoucherCreateResponseModel>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBatches; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(_client.GenerateVoucher($"CouponsCreate", request));
            vouchers.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false));
        }

        // await _voucherService.GenerateVouchers(request, clientId, _idempotentHeader);
        watch.Stop();
        var totalMS = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        return Ok();
    }
```

But the issue with above code even though I have `ConfigureAwait(false)`, it waits for all 20 requests to execute and when response of all requests are returned than api consumer will get response, but each each of these 20 request will take around 5 seconds to execute, so our consumers may get request timeout while waiting for response.

How can I fix such issue in .Net Core.

Comment: Use f.i. [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to process that kind of long running background processes

Comment: You're only effectively waiting on one task at a time, since the WhenAll call is inside your for loop. You add to the list, then wait for it to complete, and repeat. You might want to move the Tasks.WhenAll to *after* the loop. That's not really going to solve your issue, but it's definitely a problem with the posted code

Comment: So the API above has no problem. The consumers of the API have the problem of timeout, because the API is long running, and the consumers are not configured to handle the long delay. Could you show us the code of the consumers?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias actually i don't have access to consumers code, we are just providing URL to endpoint to them and we have to develop a solution in such a way that 1: let them call our api with number of records to be generated, 2: our api will call number of 3rd part endpoints, 3: will return response to consumer that operation is started, 4: will provide endpoint that will show status of their earlier api call.

Comment: What technology are the consumers? Javascript? Other C# applications?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice to wait for long running process inside controller.
My opinion is ,

1. put the data necessary (something like a Id for a batch) for long
   running process to a Azure queue within the API
2. trigger a function app from the particular queue, So API's responsibility is
   putting the data in to the queue
3. From there on it's function apps
   responsibility to complete process .
4. May be using something like
   signalR you can notify the frontend when process is completed